# Javascript binary numbers to a sentence

Tags: javascript

I need to convert these binary numbers to a sentence.

So...

```
binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111")
```

should return "Aren't bonfires fun!?"

I wrote this the below code but it's returning nothing.
I know there are way better solutions than this way but I first wanted to know why my code doesn't work.
Is there anyone happy to help me?

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let arr = str.split(" ").map(x => x.split(""));
  let newArr = [];
  let num = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].lnegth; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] === "1") {
        num += 2 ** (7 - j);
      }
      newArr.push(num);
    }
  }

  return String.fromCharCode(newArr.join(""));
}
```

Comment: `const binaryAgent = (str) => String.fromCharCode(...str.split(" ").map(v => parseInt(v, 2)));`

Answer (score 4):

You may go as simple as that:

```js
const str = "01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111",

      sentence = str
        .split(' ')
        .reduce((acc, b) => 
          acc += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b,2)), '')
        
console.log(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things wrong with your code:

1. You need to reset num at the beginning of every character block, so `let num = 0;` in your original code is misplaced.
2. You need to push the num into the arr after you're done with the character block, so `newArr.push(num);` is also misplaced.
3. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) for the `fromCharCode` method, the input should be an argument for each character, not a joined string. You need to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do this.

Putting this all together, you get the following working code:

```
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let arr = str.split(" ").map(x => x.split(""));
  let newArr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let num = 0;
    for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] === "1") {
        num += 2 ** (7 - j);
      }
    }
    newArr.push(num);
  }

  return String.fromCharCode(...newArr);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much! Yes, I always use push at a wrong place... Thank you again for your time on reviewing my code!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what General Poxter said, you have a typo in your inner for loop: `lnegth` where it should say `length`.

Comment: Ah yes I noticed that, but forgot to include it in my list! Thanks for pointing that out.